ros2 run: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
I have some Python code working that reads from a sensor connected to I2C.
As this works, I assume I have all my permissions set up correctly for the I2C interface.
I then wrote a ROS 2 wrapper for the Python code. When I try run (ros2 run) this node I get a PermissionError as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/launch/actions/execute_local.py",
line 569, in __execute_process
transport, self._subprocess_protocol = await async_execute_process(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
"/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/osrf_pycommon/process_utils/async_execute_process_asyncio/impl.py",
line 139, in async_execute_process
transport, protocol = await _async_execute_process_nopty(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/opt/ros/jazzy/lib/python3.12/site-packages/osrf_pycommon/process_utils/async_execute_process_asyncio/impl.py",
line 45, in _async_execute_process_nopty
transport, protocol = await loop.subprocess_exec(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1744, in
subprocess_exec
transport = await self._make_subprocess_transport(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 211, in
_make_subprocess_transport
transp = _UnixSubprocessTransport(self, protocol, args, shell,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_subprocess.py", line 36, in
init
self._start(args=args, shell=shell, stdin=stdin, stdout=stdout,   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 820, in _start
self._proc = subprocess.Popen(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 1026, in init
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 1840, in _execute_child
self._posix_spawn(args, executable, env, restore_signals,   File "/usr/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 1784, in _posix_spawn
self.pid = os.posix_spawn(executable, args, env, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

(address to my node in ws/install) follows "Permission denied:"
Anyone have ideas or things I can try to debug?
I have done sudo rosdep fix-permissions in the workspace.
The Python file is also executable.
Thanks.
[Jazzy, RaspberryPi5]

Hi, in your ros2 workspace, did you tried to execute "sudo chmod -R +x"

Thanks for your suggestion @Kevin_dans_son_garage_du_63 . Please see my answer below for the fix.

This has been resolved. Ultimately, it was about not using Python virtual envs and ROS 2 correctly. After adding my virtual env's site-packages address to $PYTHONPATH, it then worked.
